# How to find way to stop while loop when 1 first point meet last in polygon in python?

Tags: python

I need to calculate the perimeter of a polygon by using only coordinates.

My function:

```
def definePerimeter(xCoords, yCoords):

i = 0
sum = 0
while xCoords[i] != xCoords[i+1] and yCoords[i] != yCoords[i+1]:
    dx = xCoords[i] - xCoords[i+1]
    dy = yCoords[i] - yCoords[i+1]
    dsquared = dx**2 + dy**2
    result = math.sqrt(dsquared)
    print "The list of segments:"
    print "The segment: ", result
    i += 1
    sum = sum + result           
print  "Total 2D Perimeter is " , sum ,"m" *
```

gives wrong Perimeter (compared to ArcGIS).

How to find way to stop while loop  when 1 first point meet last in polygon in python?

Comment: Instead of presenting this as a function with two parameters, can you just give us a couple of hardwired values for `xCoords` and `yCoords` and a picture of their output, and the text of any errors?  When you say wrong Perimeter do you mean a tiny rounding error, something that looks like projection could be involved or more like a square truncated to a triangle due to too few cords being used?

Comment: Try dx=float(...), dy=float(..) and replace **2 by dx*dx+dy*dy. Also I'd use for i,x in enumerate(xCoords) for your loop

Comment: I don't see where the problem is.. all lists are finite, they start at element 0 and then go to element 'n'. A polygon in Esri has its last point coincident (right on top of and identical to) its first. When you get the array from the part for the polygon you only need iterate by range(len(Array)-1) to iterate through the polygon once. Can you explain how you're getting your arrays please, perhaps the problem is there.

Comment: Shouldn't the test be against coord[0]?

Comment: I see it migrated from gis stack, so I assume it is gis related. Are you using GDAL, shapely or another module to read the coords? What format is the polygon data in(shp, csv)?

Comment: Your while loop breaks on 2 consecutive vertices having the same coordinate. If you haven't validated geometry this might be the case. Using a for loop as proposed in Zachi's answer you are protected from such geometry problems.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a `while` loop here. You can do it with a `for` loop since you are going through all of the polygon's vertices:

```
sum = 0
for i in xrange(len(xCoords) - 1):
      sum += np.sqrt((xCoords[i] - xCoords[i + 1]) ** 2) + (yCoords[i] -yCoords[i + 1]) ** 2))
sum+=np.sqrt((xCoords[0] - xCoords[-1]) ** 2) + (yCoords[0] -yCoords[-1]) ** 2))
```

If you insist on doing so with a `while` loop you can do so in this way:

```
sum = 0
i = 0
while (i < len(xCoords) - 1):
          sum += np.sqrt((xCoords[i] - xCoords[i + 1]) ** 2) + (yCoords[i] -yCoords[i + 1]) ** 2))
          i += 1
sum+=np.sqrt((xCoords[0] - xCoords[-1]) ** 2) + (yCoords[0] -yCoords[-1]) ** 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is not correct. You need to first sort your coordinates based on the arctangent of the angle they create with the centroid of your polygon. (In order to get the correct order of your coordinates in your shape)

```
from math import atan

def sort_coordinates(centroid, shuffled_coordinates):
    Cx, Cy = centroid
    return sorted(shuffled_coordinates, key=lambda p: math.atan2(p[1]-Cy,p[0]-Cx))
```

Then you can calculate the length of the sides of shape using pair coordinates and sum up all them to get the perimeter:

```
def perimeter(coordinates):
    return sum(math.sqrt(pow(y2-y1,2)+pow(x2-x1,2)) for (x1,y1),(x2,y2) in zip(coordinates, coordinates[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your while loop condition, I am guessing your last and first coordinates are the same.

```
x = [0,1,2,3,0]

y = [0,2,4,5,0]
```

I don't see any other way in which that while loop condition makes sense. If it is so, then you should try.

```
i = math.fmod((i+1),len(xCoords))
```